# Using arrays to determine the minimum

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11, visual-studio-2013

Why this simple code is not working ?
everything seems to be alright and i get no error ( IDE : Visual studio 2013 )
anyone can help ?

```
int a[30];
int b;
int min = 0;

do {
    cin >> b;
    if (b != 0) {   
        int i = 0;
        a[i] = b;
        i++;
        if (min>a[i])
            min = a[i];
    }
} while (b != 0);

cout << endl << "THE MIN IS : "<<min<<endl;
```

Comment: Why would you need an array?  You can keep track of the minimum with a single variable.

Comment: You are incorrectly checking `a[i]` after incrementing `i`

Comment: A general tip on how to solve such issues yourself: learn how to use a debugger. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/79508/Mastering-Debugging-in-Visual-Studio-A-Beginn

Comment: You don't get an error because you have a logic error, not a syntax error. What happens if you don't type `0` as input until the 31st opportunity? Also think about how you can do this without storing the values in an array.

Comment: You should learn how to effectively ask questions before learning how to program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The program has undefined behaviour because you use an uninitialized element of the array.

In this code snippet

```
if (b != 0)
    {   
        int i = 0;
        a[i] = b;
        i++;
        if (min>a[i])
            min = a[i];

    }
```

you always compare min with a[1] that was not assigned any value. In the block statement of the if statement variable i always is created anew and initialized by 0. Then it is increased and you compare min with a[1]. But it is only a[0] that was assigned.

In fact you need no any array. The code can be written the following way

```
bool empty = true;
int min;
int value;

while ( std::cin >> value && value != 0 )
{
   if ( empty || value < min )
   {
      empty = false;
      min = value;
   }
}

if ( !empty ) std::cout << "\nThe minimum is equal to " << min << std::endl;
else std::cout << "\nYou did not enter any number" << std::endl;
```

If you need to store values in an array then the code could look the following way

```
const size_t N = 30;
int a[N];
int value;

size_t i = 0;

while ( i < N && std::cin >> value && value != 0 ) a[i++] = value;

if ( i != 0 )
{
   int min = a[0];

   for ( size_t j = 1; j < i; j++ )
   {
      if ( a[j] < min ) min = a[j];
   }

   std::cout << "\nThe minimum is equal to " << min << std::endl;
}
else
{
    std::cout << "\nYou did not enter any number" << std::endl;
}
```

Take into account that there is standard algorithm `std::min_element`   declared in header `<algorithm>` in C++.

Comment: I've been asked to store the values in an array in my practice book .
Don't blame me !!!
I've been adding 1 value to i before i check it by a mistake .
I'm a bit careless , maybe not a bit .

Comment: @Er Fun See my updated post.